# Drupal 7 CKeditor always saves Array

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am developing a custom module with some entities inside. I created a form to edit them and I would like to use CKEditor in one of the fields.

I can see and use the CKEditor, but when it's time to save, it always saves the value 'Array'. You can find the code I am using below:

```
$form['description'] = array(
        '#type' => 'text_format',
        '#format' => 'full_html',
        '#title' => t('Content'),
        '#default_value' => $entity->content,
        '#weight' =>2,
        '#required' => FALSE,
    );
```

I'd say CKEditor changes the value before sending the form POST but I am not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may help http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33254/saving-a-field-of-type-text-format-as-a-system-setting-variable

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that was easier than I thought. When using WYSIWYG editors you have to save the info differently.

For a normal textarea:

```
$entity->content = $form_state['values']['description']
```

For a WYSIWYG:

```
$entity->content = $form_state['values']['description']['value']
```